# Display divs one above the other

Tags: reactjs, grid, tailwind-css

```
import React from "react";

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="grid"
        style={{
          gridTemplateColumns: "1.75rem repeat(288, minmax(0, 1fr)) auto",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="mt-px inline-grid grid-cols-1 sm:col-start-3"
          style={{ gridColumn: "74 / span 12" }}
        >
          <a href="#" className="rounded-lg bg-blue-50 p-2 text-xs">
            <p className="order-1 font-semibold text-blue-700">Breakfast</p>
            <p className="text-blue-500 group-hover:text-blue-700">
              <time dateTime="2022-01-12T06:00">6:00 AM</time>
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div
          className="mt-px inline-grid grid-cols-1 sm:col-start-3"
          style={{ gridColumn: "76 / span 12" }}
        >
          <a href="#" className="rounded-lg bg-blue-50 p-2 text-xs">
            <p className="order-1 font-semibold text-blue-700">Breakfast</p>
            <p className="text-blue-500 group-hover:text-blue-700">
              <time dateTime="2022-01-12T06:00">6:30 AM</time>
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the tiles over one another , add `absolute w-1/4 right-4` class to both the divs.

```
import React from "react";

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="grid"
        style={{
          gridTemplateColumns: "1.75rem repeat(288, minmax(0, 1fr)) auto",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="absolute w-1/4 right-4 mt-px inline-grid grid-cols-1 sm:col-start-3"
          style={{ gridColumn: "74 / span 12" }}
        >
          <a href="#" className="rounded-lg bg-blue-50 p-2 text-xs">
            <p className="order-1 font-semibold text-blue-700">Breakfast</p>
            <p className="text-blue-500 group-hover:text-blue-700">
              <time dateTime="2022-01-12T06:00">6:00 AM</time>
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div
          className="absolute w-1/4 right-4 mt-px inline-grid grid-cols-1 sm:col-start-3"
          style={{ gridColumn: "76 / span 12" }}
        >
          <a href="#" className="rounded-lg bg-blue-50 p-2 text-xs">
            <p className="order-1 font-semibold text-blue-700">Breakfast</p>
            <p className="text-blue-500 group-hover:text-blue-700">
              <time dateTime="2022-01-12T06:00">6:30 AM</time>
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> you can adjust `right` and `width` as per your requirement .